# How to give path to identify OU when we have nested OU's in active directory while creating a user in active directory in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

Using

```
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "me.com", "OU=Menetwork OU=Users OU=IT")
```

I am working on directory programing and I want to know how can I give path for OU when we have nested OUs in active directory while creating a User in active Directory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A Directory is a tree of objects. Each object OUs (containers), user (leaf in your case) is addressed by a distinguished name wich is composed by an `attribute=value` pair suffixed by the distinguished name of his container. The following two screenshots show you the two visions, MMC one and the LDAP one with all the DNs.

[image: AD MMC vision][image: AD LDP vision]

In my case here is how I can create a user in an nested OU like this :

```
/* Creating a user
 * Retreiving a principal context
 */
PrincipalContext domainContextMonou = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "WM2008R2ENT:389", "ou=SousMonou,ou=Monou,dc=dom,dc=fr", "user", "pass");

/* Create a user principal object
 */
UserPrincipal aSlxUser = new slxUser(domainContextMonou, "user3.users", "pass@1w0rd01", true);

/* assign some properties to the user principal
 */
aSlxUser.GivenName = "user3";
aSlxUser.Surname = "users";

/* Force the user to change password at next logon
 */
//aSlxUser.ExpirePasswordNow();

/* save the user to the directory
 */
aSlxUser.Save();

/* set the password to a new value
 */
aSlxUser.SetPassword("test.2013");
aSlxUser.Save();
```

Comment: Interesting, so the takeaway message I get is that paths are specified backwards. Thanks.

Comment: I spent 1 hour trying to figure out why was getting an error when trying to get users on a nested OU. Turns out that I was starting from parent OU instead of starting with the leaf OU. Saved me!